# Build phonegap windows8 project using command line

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-8, command-line

I want to build a phonegap project (on windows 8.1) for windows 8 but somehow I get an error. Building a Android project goes without any errors. When I run the command 'phonegap run windows8' I get the following error:
[image]

I also tried 'phonegap install windows8', same problem. I installed phonegap last week using 'npm install -g phonegap'. Maybe a stupid question, but how do I know I use the latest release (currently 2.9.1)? When I do 'phonegap version' it returns 3.3.0-0.18.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed cordova instead of phonegap in my command-line (npm install cordova). with cordova everything went just fine. I searched in the platform list of the phonegap install and noticed phonegap doesn't support windows 8. Very confusing since the phonegap website tells us to install phonegap instead of cordova. If anyone has question about building a app phonegap for windows 8 let me know.

Comment: Windows 8 is supported, it's just not supported through the CLI, You have to download the SDK's locally and build your application through the local method. [Supported Platforms](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_support_index.md.html#Platform%20Support)

Comment: I'm sorry, that's true. Forgot to mention that I was only talking about the CLI.

Comment: `cordova build windows8` also throws an error. Have you got that working or are you copying the files manually? Happy to start a new question if that makes sense.

Comment: I didn't have an error... I did when I used jQuery, but there are multiple sollutions for that. What does your error say?